# PyQt draw elements depending of ComboBox state

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I want to be able to dynamically draw the UI depending of which element in a QComboBox is currently selected. I used the QT Designer to make the design and changed the code based on the output of the designer. Here was my idea:

```
class Anim_Window(object):
def setupUi(self, parent):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("Anim_Window")
    MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.chooseActionCombo = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.chooseActionCombo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 151, 31))
    self.chooseActionCombo.setObjectName("chooseActionCombo")
    self.chooseActionCombo.addItem("Rotate")
    self.chooseActionCombo.addItem("Color")
    self.chooseActionCombo.addItem("Skew")
    self.chooseActionCombo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.select_action)
    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
def select_action(self):
        if self.chooseActionCombo.currentText() == "Rotate":
            self.action_rotate()
        elif self.chooseActionCombo.currentText() == "Color":
            self.action_color() 
def action_rotate(self):
        print("entered")
        self.rotLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.rotLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 50, 211, 16))
        self.rotLabel.setObjectName("rotLabel")
        
        self.retranslate_rotate()
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.chooseActionCombo.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Rotate"))
        self.chooseActionCombo.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Color"))
def retranslate_rotate(self):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.rotLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Rotation Point"))
        self.inputXLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "X:"))
        self.inputYLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Y:"))
        self.saveValuesButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save values"))
```

I skipped a lot of lines but this is basically what I came up with, seemed very straight forward to me but apparently this will not redraw the window. So how I could I tell the MainWindow to draw itself after each call?

Comment: There are various problems with your attempt, but most importantly: 1. the pyuic code should **never** be manually edited (see how to properly use ui files in the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)); 2. you should not create new widgets every time, but only create them once and eventually switch between them; consider using [QStackedWidget](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html); in any case, the code doesn't work as creating child widgets *after* the parent is shown doesn't make them visible unless you call `show()`.

Comment: Also note that you should never used fixed geometries, but use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), which can also be created in [Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).

Comment: Thank you @musicamante , that was very helpful. I resolved the issue by using the stacked widget as you suggested, not it works just fine.